# Pan-across animation between views in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, ng-animate

I'm building an AngularJS app and am looking to do something a little tricky with animations that I'm not quite sure how to do. One aspect of the app entails animation **between views** in a panning manner, but the appearance of a single view needs to be maintained. For example, if there is a scene with a square in the center, on view-change that square would appear to leave the screen as if we were panning across (while other elements enter in), all without it feeling like the view has really changed.

I know that `ng-animate` provides a lot of powerful animation functionality, but I'm stumped on what the best way to maintain the appearance of a single view while transitioning between them is.

Does anyone have experience trying to do this or know of an animation library that would make this possible?

I'll update this question with possible solutions as I find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a view is added, the following classes are added:

```
 .ng-enter
 .ng-enter.ng-enter-active
```

When a view is removed, the following classes are added:

```
 .ng-leave
 .ng-leave.ng-leave-active
```

You can attach CSS 3 transition styles to the classes to achieve the animation effect you want.

If I understand correctly, the 'leaving' animation should pan left to right, and fade-out, starting from a 0px offset.  The 'entering' animation should also pan left to right, but fade-in, starting from a negative offset.

Here is an example:

[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jzHmf522m1RqXqB8Lzaz?p=preview) 
[JS FIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9YD5g/)

Comment: That seems to be something that will work! I'll be putting together some proofs of concept and will post what I find on here. Thanks for your help!